# Convert a Matrix like report to columns using GAWK

Tags: csv, awk

I'm new to awk and have tried to convert a report in CSV in a matrix format to a tabular format.

This is what my input file looks like.

```
Object,CompanyA,CompanyB,CompanyC
10001,100.50,200.00,250.00
10002,0,100.00,130.00
10003,0,200.00,175.00
```

and this is how it should look like.

```
Object,Company,Amount
10001,CompanyA, 150.00
10002,CompanyA, 0
10003,CompanyA, 0
10001,CompanyB, 200.00
10002,CompanyB, 100.00
10003,CompanyB, 200.00
10001,CompanyC, 250.00
10002,CompanyC, 130.00
10003,CompanyC, 175.00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in traditional awk, no need for gawk.

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){name[i]=$i}} NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,name[i],$i;}}' inputfile.txt
```

Let's break this apart for easier reading.  If it were a standalone script, it might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    OFS=",";
}

# On the first line, gather field names from the column heads...
NR==1 {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        name[i]=$i;
    }
}

# And on subsequent lines, walk through the fields and print output for each.
NR>1 {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        print $1,name[i],$i;
    }
}
```

If you want the output to be sorted by the second column, as in your example, you can use the `sort` command:

```
$ awk '...' inputfile.txt | sort -t, -k2
```

Note that sort's `-k` option lets you specify both start and stop positions for your sort, but not a *secondary* sort.  So if you want output sorted like your example, you'll need more tools.  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ vals[NR][1]; split($0,vals[NR]) }
END {
    print vals[1][1], "Company", "Amount"
    for (fld=2;fld<=NF;fld++) {
        for (rec=2;rec<=NR;rec++) {
            print vals[rec][1], vals[1][fld], vals[rec][fld]
        }
    }
}
' file
Object,Company,Amount
10001,CompanyA,100.50
10002,CompanyA,0
10003,CompanyA,0
10001,CompanyB,200.00
10002,CompanyB,100.00
10003,CompanyB,200.00
10001,CompanyC,250.00
10002,CompanyC,130.00
10003,CompanyC,175.00
```

With other awks you'd just populate vals[NR] in a loop of the fields instead of using split() and you'd use vals[a,b] instead of vals[a][b] syntax:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ for (fld=1; fld<=NF; fld++) vals[NR,fld] = $fld }
END {
    print vals[1,1], "Company", "Amount"
    for (fld=2;fld<=NF;fld++) {
        for (rec=2;rec<=NR;rec++) {
            print vals[rec,1], vals[1,fld], vals[rec,fld]
        }
    }
}
' file
Object,Company,Amount
10001,CompanyA,100.50
10002,CompanyA,0
10003,CompanyA,0
10001,CompanyB,200.00
10002,CompanyB,100.00
10003,CompanyB,200.00
10001,CompanyC,250.00
10002,CompanyC,130.00
10003,CompanyC,175.00
```